# Difference between developing for a Jailbroken iOS Platform and using Private API's

Tags: ios, iphone-privateapi

What is the main difference between developing for Jailbroken iOS device and just using Private API's on a non-jailbroken device?

I am trying to develop something similar to [Veency](http://cydia.saurik.com/info/veency/) privately for a device and I want to know the limitations I will face (the only one I am familiar with is the sandbox doesn't let apps read files outside the sandbox).

Answer (score 1):

*Private APIs* are the APIs that are **not** documented by apple. You can use them either on a jailbroken or a non-jailbroken device. but the limitations you might find is the 3rd party libraries that can be installed on jailbroken devices that might allow you to build tweak apps more easily.

You may want to check [Mobile Substrate](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/MobileSubstrate) as an example for more details.